# plink.exe : Getting non valid character in output

Tags: c#, ssh, putty, plink

I am using **plink.exe** to execute commands on remote server. I am able to connect with remote server but when I execute a command to server, it returns with invalid characters output like:

> [?7l[H[2J[?25l[1;1H[37m[40m[2;1H[3;1H[4;1H[5;1H[6;1H[7;1H[8;1H[9;1H[10;1H[11;1H
>   [12;1H[13;1H[14;1H[15;1H[16;1H[17;1H[18;1H[19;1H[20;1H[21;1H[22;1H[23;1H[24;1H
>   [?12l[?25h[1;1HMicrosoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601][2;1HCopyright (c)
>   2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights
>   reserved.[4;1HC:\Users\Admin>dir /r[5;1H Volume in drive C is
>   UneqSol[6;1H Volume Serial Number is 02F3-A323[8;1H Directory of
>   C:\Users\Admin[10;1H06/17/2014  08:18 PM    
>   .[11;1H06/17/2014  08:18 PM              ..[12;1H03/08/2014 
>   11:39 AM              .android[13;1H03/08/2014  11:34 AM    
>   .AndroidStudioPreview[14;1H06/04/2014  09:39 PM                65
>   .gplink_config[15;1H03/08/2014  11:26 AM    
>   .gradle[16;1H07/10/2013  07:44 PM    
>   .idlerc[17;1H08/18/2013  03:10 PM             1,189
>   .opgalaxy7.vr[18;1H03/11/2013  10:59 PM    
>   .swt[19;1H02/22/2014  08:47 PM    
>   .VirtualBox[20;1H07/06/2013  05:52 PM    
>   Contacts[21;1H06/08/2014  02:58 PM    
>   Desktop[22;1H11/23/2013  01:37 PM    
>   Dir[23;1H06/17/2014  09:39 PM    
>   Documents[24;1H06/17/2014  07:01 PM              Downloads[24;1H

My code to connect with server is:

```
 m_Process = new Process();
 m_Process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
 m_Process.StartInfo.FileName = "plink.exe";
 m_Process.StartInfo.Arguments = "-ssh admin@localhost -pw test";
 m_Process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
 m_Process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
 m_Process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
 m_Process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
 m_Process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
 m_Process.OutputDataReceived += m_Process_OutputDataReceived;

 m_Process.Exited += delegate(object sender, EventArgs ev)
 {
     m_CloseCallback(true);
 };

 m_Process.Start();
 m_Process.BeginOutputReadLine();
 m_Process.BeginErrorReadLine();

 StreamWriter strw = m_Process.StandardInput;
 strw.WriteLine("dir /r"); // send commands 

 // Wait for application to start and become idle
 m_Process.WaitForExit();
```

And in event of data received, i am getting above output,

```
 private static void m_Process_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
 {
    string value = e.Data;
 }
```

If any one can identify the issue, that would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure those aren't just escape characters which are meant to control text colour etc?

Comment: i am not sure about these, but if these are, then how i can get removed these ?

Comment: You might want to look at the plink documentation, particularly around agent forwarding etc.

Comment: Didn't get any stuff related to this. There are a lot of posts related to using plink.exe in c# and all are using these methods and i am wondering no one is facing or highlighting this issue. Might be some issue with my machine configuration, but now sure.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the encoding of the output

```
m_Process.StartInfo.StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.ASCII;
m_Process.StartInfo.StandardErrorEncoding = Encoding.ASCII;
```

This is untested. You might need a different Encoding: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.aspx

Comment: Same output, Nothing changed. Used some other encoding also.